# Value missing though required retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.0 to create retrofit service for uploading file on server.

I am refering https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Below is my FileUploadService code:

```
interface TripHistoryFileUploadService {
@Multipart
@POST("trip/trip-history")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("json_file") RequestBody description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

}

I am using below retrofit version:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
```

But I am getting error **Value missing though required** like below:

[image]

Can any one face same problem or any one have solution for the same?

Comment: Have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571549/4199996](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571549/4199996) and compile 2.0.2 instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> beta Version is An early version of a program or application that
>   contains most of the major features, but is not yet complete.

You should use Stable

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2' //A type-safe HTTP client
```

Then **`Clean -Rebuild-Sync`** Your IDE .Hope this helps you .

Comment: @pRaNaY Glad to hear .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **part name** to the second argument

```
interface TripHistoryFileUploadService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("trip/trip-history")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("json_file") RequestBody description,
                          @Part("part_name_missing here") MultipartBody.Part file);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in similar situation and it turns out to be trivial thing - I've imported Part from first version of retrofit instead of second.
So at least you can do is tu check if you have

```
import retrofit.http.Part; -> requires value
```

instead of

```
import retrofit2.http.Part; -> doesn't required value
```